# Ошибки или неясности в формулировке

Tags: общие-вопросы

Нашел в Интернете. Цитирую:

«Правильно изменяй формы слов

(есть) высокая стена

(нет) высокой стены

(подойду к) высокой стене

(вижу) высокую стену

(любуюсь) высокой стеной

(говорю о) высокой стене».

«Звуки речи, слоги и ударение изучает фонетика (фон — значит «звук»). Обозначение звуков речи на письме изучает графика (графо  — значит «пишу»).»

Мама второклассницы Наталия Годунова рассказывает про учебники русского языка программы «Начальная школа XXI века». Формулировки в книге такие, что и взрослому человеку понять правила с первого раза трудно. А дети после занятий фонетикой начали исправлять «корову» на «карову».

Кто-нибудь сможет объяснить, что не так с формулировками, есть ли ошибки? Почему мать ученицы так негодует?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Программа «Начальная школа XXI века» на самом деле продвинутая, для умных детей. Когда её создавали, имели в виду, что современное поколение - акселераты, но не учли, что далеко не все акселераты, а теперь вот медики говорят вообще о снижении отдельных способностей детей (им легче понять работу гаджетов, чем логику человеческой речи).Нельзя по ним учить детей со слабыми умственными способностями, детей нужно отбирать. А родителям нужно просто держать контакт с учителем, приходить, звонить - спрашивать, что не поняли.

Учебники написаны нормально, для умных детей понятно, я удивлялась, когда в 5 классе, обучающемся по этой программе, все дети фонетический анализ делали безукоризненно, а вот в 9 (кот. учился по  обычным учебникам)50% не справлялись с анализом этих же слов.Орфографических ошибок они как раз делают очень мало по сравнению с обучающимися по другим учебникам,у них развиты творческие способности. Ко мне моя бывшая ученица привела свою дочь: "Помогите, я не могу проверить свою дочь, она говорит так, а я считаю по-другому". Дочь оказалась права. Дети понимают, а взрослые нет, их же так не учили. Беда в другом - потом эти дети попадают к другим учителям, учатся по обычным учебникам, и всё наработанное ими пропадает.

О формах одного слова там тоже всё верно сказано. У слова есть начальная форма, вот её мы и меняем: стена - стены, стене, стену, стеной, о стене. Слово одно, а форма слова меняется, существительное изменяется по падежам и числам. Что же здесь неверно? Какая разница, как сказать -подобрать верную форму или изменить форму? Отличать слово от формы слова тоже очень важно, дети, обучающиеся по этой программе, делают это легко, доказывая, что у слова есть лексическое значение, оно не меняется, а грамматическая форма у слова меняется.

Comment: Спасибо за профессиональный ответ. Вот и мне показалось преувеличенным это негодование. Причем программа получила премию Президента Российской Федерации в области образования.

Comment: О школе 21 века много отрицательных отзывов,  а премии всегда получают "те, кто надо".  И авторам программы она наверняка очень нравится. Здесь статистика нужна, так трудно судить, но отзывы кажутся искренними.  Вот некоторые из них: (1) Я не говорю уже о способности самого ребенка сделать самому дз. Это невозможно. У нас весь класс списывает с решебников. В учебниках очень мало теоретической части, одни вопросы: "А как ты думаешь? Как по-твоему?" Меня это просто бесит.

Comment: (2) Я в шоке!!! Как можно первокласснику задать такое?
Кошке, собаке и попугаю вместе 9 лет.
Кошке и собаке вместе 6 лет, а Кошке и попугаю вместе 7 лет. 
Сколько лет кошке, собаке, и попугаю?
0-о Это по какому принципу он должен действовать?????
нельзя было хоть одной твари возраст указать????  Да, решить, конечно, можно,  но способно  ли детское мышление  держать под контролем  4 величины сразу. У меня соседка ходит в 1 класс, надо на ней проверить.

Comment: Можно, можно, и труднее есть задачи. Это задачи в несколько действий. Попугаю 9 - 6 = 3 ( года ) 
Собаке 9 - 7 = 2 ( года ) 
Кошке 9 - ( 3 + 2 ) = 9 - 5 = 4 ( года ) . Можно по-другому. Попугаю 9 - 6 = 3 ( года ), кошке 7-3 = 4(года), собаке 9-7 = 2  Внучка приятельницы труднее приносила, она решила быстрее нас, взрослых. Может, эта программа и делает их умнее нас.

Answer (score 1):

Можно предположить, что из определения "пишу - значит обозначаю звуки" ребёнок вывел инструкцию: как слышим, так и пишем.

Comment: На мой взгляд, формулировка нормальная. Если дети пишут кАрова, виноваты не учебники, а педагог.

Comment: Причем она возмущается, что и взрослым тяжело понять формулировки.

Comment: Польза этого абзаца в этом месте и на этом этапе обучения неочевидна.

Answer (score 1):

1) Надо говорить: **правильно подбирай формы слова**. Формы слова – это основа с разными окончаниями, они не изменяются. (Это **ошибка).**

2) Подробнее надо писать для детей.

Фон (греч. phone) – значит "звук". Графо (греч. grapho) – значит "пишу". Эти слова заимствованы из греческого языка.

А от про "карову" – **это верно**. В школе сначала изучают звуковую запись, дети ее **запоминают**, поэтому им потом трудно перейти на фонематическое письмо.

Comment: Насчет формы слова согласен. А вот говорить из какого языка заимствованы слова фон и графо - нет смысла. Педагог объяснять, что слова не всегда пишутся, как  слышаться.

Comment: Не знаю, что там объясняет педагог, но в учебнике объясняется как раз происхождение слов. Почему науку о звуках мы называем фонетикой, ведь у нас нет такого корня.  Откуда взялся этот "фон"? Вот и надо скзать, что корень здесь греческий (как, кстати, и в слове телефон). Буква О  копируется  из греческого слова, а в устной речи безударный звук О произносится как А, но это только в устной речи. Вот такая информация была бы  полезной

Comment: Но только не в начальных классах.

Comment: При таком подходе эта информация вообще не нужна. С другой стороны, дети  сейчас чуть ли не с пеленок начинают изучать иностранные языки, и к школе в этой теме они уже вполне продвинутые.  А в русском языке много  заимствованных слов, поэтому работать с этимологическим словарем надо начинать уже в младших классах. Чем заучивать отдельные слова, лучше, к примеру,  сразу запомнить, что манеж, манжета, маневр, манипулировать, манера  имеют общий исторический корень manus - рука, поэтому пишутся с буквой А.

Comment: Такой подход очень интересный, но, на мой взгляд, не в начальных классах.

Comment: Знаете, в образовании есть два подхода. Классический - это линейный, когда проходим что-то по порядку (обычно мимо).. И другой - от центра к периферии (принцип развивающего обучения). Что это значит? Младшие школьники должны усвоить сначала принцип  хотя бы на самых простых словах, а потом словарный объем будет постепенно расширяться. А то у нас, к примеру,  как делают: проходят всю фонетику в младших классах, а потом всё забывают или повторяют всё на том же уровне, на детском уровне. А этого недостаточно. чтобы писать грамотно.

Comment: В школьной практике принято понятие *начальная форма*, которая, собственно, и изменяется. Так что ошибки никакой нет.

Comment: Допустим, у вас 12 форм существительного, одна из них начальная.  Что с ними можно сделать? Из словаря: 3. (св. переменить и СМЕНИТЬ). . Заменить одно другим. . 4. (св. ИЗМЕНИТЬ и переменить). что. Сделать иным. Так вот: форму слова НЕЛЬЗЯ СДЕЛАТЬ ИНОЙ, но можно ее переменить, сменить, заменить, то есть ВЫБРАТЬ ДРУГУЮ.  Точно так же можно выбрать чашку или стакан, но НЕЛЬЗЯ ИЗМЕНИТЬ чашку и сделать ее стаканом.

Comment: Вам не кажется, что Вы перепутали понятия форма слова и словоформа?Форму слова как раз можно изменить - изменить окончание у слова, а вот словоформу можно заменить одну на другую.Ваше образное сравнение с чашкой тоже касается словоформы, но не грамматической формы слова. Форма слова - это грамматический вид, его можно изменить, а вот словоформу (слово в определённой форме) можно только заменить другой словоформой.

Comment: Это еще вопрос: кто и что перепутал, у меня на этот счет другое мнение, если это позволяется. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Форма_слова "Термин «форма слова» может употребляться как по отношению к конкретному слову (словоформе), так и по отношению к классу грамматических форм с одинаковым грамматическим значением, представленных в разных словах" .  Розенталь словоформы  свободно называет  грамматическими формами. Термин неоднозначен.  Вы напишите хотя бы "правильно изменяй форму слова", а не "формы слова", потому что формы слова - это именно словоформы.

Comment: И разумеется,  дети во втором классе  свободно разбираются в этих терминах. "Стена" - это форма или словоформа, а "стены" - это что, словоформа или форма? К примеру, есть грамматическая форма ед. или мн. числа, или повелит. наклонения, тогда это, разумеется, не словоформа, термины имеют разное значение. Но если речь идет о конкретном слове, то нет необходимости отличать грамматическую форму слова от его словоформы. Одна из словоформ названа начальной формой - вот и все сложности этого вопроса.

Comment: Во-первых, это не я, а авторы учебника писали "правильно изменяй формы слова", (хотя и это приемлемо), во-вторых, в начальной школе нет, слава богу, термина словоформа (дети отличают слово от формы слова), это уж мы с Вами терминами обмениваемся, в-третьих, здесь речь идёт именно о грамматической форме слова: стены - форма ед.ч., род.пад. Почему ж нельзя изменить эту форму, т.е. окончание, которое её и создаёт? Изменить форму или заменить форму на форму множ. числа или другого падежа - одно и то же. Это уже придирки.

Comment: Когда-то я тоже училась в школе, был круглой отличницей и "всё понимала". На самом деле я понимала далеко не всё, но при этом выполняла правильно все задания, учителя были очень довольны и хвалили меня. Моё же понимание было чисто условным:  это было интуитивно правильно поведение в не очень понятном мире.  Позже, уже во взрослой жизни,  я стала стараться не оставлять белых пятен в понимании чего-либо. И я почти уверена, что любого из младших школьников можно из всё понимающего превратить в ничего не понимающего, просто задав ему пару нужных вопросов. Но я не уверена, что это надо делать..

Comment: С другой стороны, не надо доверять их "пониманию" - дети могут искусно притворяться знающими. И вывод: в каждом возрасте ребенку доступен определенный уровень знаний, его он должен усвоить ясно, поэтому школе 21 века не стоит гнаться за быстрым, но  мнимым успехом.  Не навреди - вот главная заповедь педагога.